# Error passing a SKNode as parameter for a function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to pass a SKNode as a parameter of a function, so I can access the SKNode's attributes such as position/p in the function.

```swift
class GameScene: SKScene {


     let node = SKShapeNode()
     let swipeRightRec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
     var pathToDraw = CGMutablePath()


     override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        pathToDraw.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0))
        pathToDraw.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 125.0, y: 50.0))
        node.path = pathToDraw

        //trying to pass created node in the swipedRight function
        swipeRightRec.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.swipedRight(node)))
        swipeRightRec.direction = .right
        self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRightRec)
     }

      // the swipe right function that accepts a SKShapeNode
      @objc func swipedRight(node: SKShapeNode) {
         let path = node.path
      }

}
```

The error I receive is:

Instance member 'swipedRight' cannot be used on type 'GameScene'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the target/action pattern the (first) parameter of any action is required to be the object which performs the action

```
@objc func swipedRight(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) { ... }
```

and add the selector just with the method name

```
swipeRightRec.addTarget(self, action: #selector(swipedRight))
```

But as the node is a property anyway it's not necessary to pass it as parameter.

Comment: But then how can I alter the node's path relative to its original path? 
That is what I am trying to do in 'swipedRight'

Comment: Just use the line you have. `node` is available in the action.